# How to get access to data storage on Amazon S3 using access key, secret key and working bucket ID?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm a beginner to Amazon S3. My partner gave me access key, secret key and working bucket ID for access data storage on Amazon S3. I found this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-custom-url.html
It's the description of how to generate the URL for access. I found there the Python script. My question is: how to use this script? For example, I copy it and paste to PyCharm. And what else? How to modify it to get desired URL? How to pass access key, secret key and working bucket ID to this script? What is 'ACCOUNT-ID-WITHOUT-HYPHENS' in this script?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/3998

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
key = s3.get_bucket('media.yourdomain.com').get_key('examples/first_file.csv')
key.get_contents_to_filename('/myfile.csv')
```

from 
https://aws.amazon.com/articles/3998